# Iterating through a list of strings in a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have declare a temporary table @OrgTable and I'm populating it with a single column of strings which represent organisation codes.
Prior to populating @OrgTable the codes are part of a continuous string which are delimited by a '|'.
I have written a function SplitString to do just that and the individual codes are then inserted into the table.
Finally I'm calling a second function, NBOCAP, into which I pass a start date, and end date and each organisation code from @OrgTable so I need to modify my script so it iterates through each organisation code. What form should my script take please? It needs to be backwards compatible with SQL2000.

```
DECLARE @OrgTable TABLE
(
    elem varchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO @OrgTable
SELECT * FROM SplitString(@OrgCodeString, '|')

SELECT * FROM NBOCAP(@StartDate,@EndDate,organisation code)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cursor`s which is compatible with sql 2000 as

```
declare @elem varchar(1000)

declare c cursor for
select elem from @OrgTable

open c
Fetch next from c into @elem

while @@fetch_Status = 0
begin
  --you have elem here
  NBOCAP(@StartDate,@EndDate,@elem)
  Fetch next from c into @elem
end

close c
deallocate c
```

or you can write your query as below:

```
DECLARE @OrgTable TABLE
(
    elem varchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO @OrgTable
SELECT * FROM SplitString(@OrgCodeString, '|')

Select n.* from @OrgTable o inner join
NBOCAP(@StartDate,@EndDate,o.elem) n
```